# I'm trying to create an add function for arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

This add function will take a single parameter which will be the item to be added to the array. I've tried using a for loop but it didn't work as I expected it to. I'm currently just trying to do something like this:

```
    bool homeworklist::add (homework h)
    {
    int i = 0;

    if(current_size < LIST_MAX){

        current_size += 1;

        list[i] = h;

        ++i;

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

current_size is just a counter.
list is a array that belongs to a homeworklist class
list takes in homework objects.
The function returns true if the object was added succesfully and false if it wasnt added correctly.

Comment: `list [i] = h;` is overwriting the first element.

Comment: This makes little sense without knowing what type anything is.

Comment: yea, it is. I dont know how to make it so that the position of the array will change to the next availble spot, each time the function is called.

Comment: Are you trying to insert it at the beginning, end, or some other location?

Comment: the beginning, im pretty much trying to make it so it works the same way the add method in java arrays work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `i` is local, which means each time you call this function, it is initialized to 0, due to this line:

```
int i = 0;
```

This in turn means in the subsequent `if` statement, you are assigning the element to the first location, **everytime**.

You could make `i` a class member, just like how you might have declared `current_size`. Or might be you could just make use of `current_size` itself.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Ill remember this the next time i have a similar problem.